# Spring JPA - find by entity in collection

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I am using `JPARepository` in my Spring Boot app and would like to make use of its queryMethods.

My example entity model looks as follows (I am omitting Hibernate annotations):

```
public class Author {
  int id;
  List<Book> books;
}

public class Book {
  int id;
  Author author;
}
```

Now, I know I can get list of books by Author using `findByAuthor(int id)` in the `BookRepository`.

Now, if this was Many-To-Many relationship and books could have more authors:

```
public class Book {
  int id;
  List<Author> author;
}
```

...is there a possibility to implement `findByAuthor(int id)` which would return a collection of books whre this author occurs? Or do I have to write my custom `@Query`?

Comment: User @OneToMany annotation to achieve this.

Comment: Follow this link to understand it better. https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/

Comment: Thank you @Gimby That's what I was looking for. The other two comments are not relevant.